# How to unselect the parent checkbox when their child checkbox is unchecked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using asp.net tree view control. And using jQuery to select all the corresponding child check box when its parent is checked. The working jQuery and the rendered HTML is in this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srk1982/Gak2h/7/)

jQuery to select the checkbox :

```
  $('.tree').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
         var checked = this.checked;
         var $elem = $(this).closest('table');
         var depth = $elem.find('div').length;
         var $childs = $elem.nextAll('table');
         $childs.each(function () {
             var $child = $(this);
             var d = $child.find('div').length;
             if (d <= depth) {
                 return false;
             }

             $child.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
         });
     });
```

But I do not know how to unselect the parent node when one of its child item is checked.

Comment: careful with confidential data exposed on the internet, I think that for Healthcare related software development you signed a NDA or something... just saying :)

Comment: Please post more of the actual code (HTML, especially) in your question. The fiddle is helpful, but your question should still stand on its own if jsfiddle were to disappear tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the weirdest structure i ever saw, anyway here is your solution
http://jsfiddle.net/Gak2h/6/
if you want to uncheck when all elements is unchecked change

```
$this.prop('checked', nbOfCheckeds == 0);
```

Comment: Your script works only for the tree with similar structure. Since the data is dynamic the tree may have any number of child records. The script dosent work when there are only two levels. Have updated my fiddle with that scenario as well

Comment: Please post the actual code in your response instead of just the fiddle link. The fiddle is helpful, but your answer should still stand on its own if jsfiddle were to disappear tomorrow.

Comment: @Anuya why do you create table for each checkbox? And why you dont put child elements in parents menu? Do you know that tables make render very slow and that this solution require alot of resiources, i could implement recursion, but its too time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this after the `$childs.each({...});` (which you migh want to rename to children.each)

```
     if(!checked){
          $elem.prev("table").find(":checkbox:first").prop('checked',false);
     }
```

it traverses up the DOM to find the preceeding table element that's is the parent in the tree to the current node and then finds the first checkbox in that which should be the parent check box

it would then be

```
$('.tree').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
     var checked = this.checked;
     var $elem = $(this).closest('table');
     var depth = $elem.find('div').length;
     var $childs = $elem.nextAll('table');
     $childs.each(function () {
         var $child = $(this);
         var d = $child.find('div').length;
         if (d <= depth) {
             return false;
         }

         $child.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
     });
     if(!checked){
          var len = $elem.find("tr:first>td").length; 
          for(;
              $elem.find("tr:first>td").length=len;
              $elem = $elem.prev("table")){}
          $elem.find(":checkbox:first").prop('checked',false);
     }
 });
```

Comment: When unchecking a node, this code unchecks the previous node. Try Selecting all the check box by clicking on parent node and then start unchecking from the bottom. You can notice it

Comment: Have updated the fiddle in the question with more appropriate scenario. Please help

Comment: @anuya the fiddle doesn't work in IE10 on my machine so I can't test for you

Comment: @anuya however from looking at the html I can see that I misunderstood the structure of it the first time so the way I tried to pick the parent was wrong. That's updated with a somewhat weird for loop. The weirdness is mostly due to the unusual structure of the html were something that is hierachical in nature is flattened in the representation